# Best way to store values related to columns of a mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs, laravel

Apologies if the question is unclear. Its hard to convey without explaining. So I'm dynamically getting table data from mysql database, and using it in my front-end React app. In my front-end I have a columns array which contains objects. Each object has different attributes like title, field, type,hidden, etc... Each of these objects represent a column and it's associated settings. I have already dynamically got the column name and I know how to get the type, but I'm not sure how to store the boolean settings like editable, filtering and hidden.

I thought of possibly storing them in a JSON config file or creating a separate table just to store all the settings for each column.

```
    //use map function to create columns from column_fields in props
    const columns2 = props.column_fields.map(column_name => {
        return (
            //TODO: correctly configure all attributes
            {title:column_name, field:column_name, type:'string', editable:'true', filtering:'true', editable:'true', hidden:'false'}
        )
    })
```

Comment: `editable: true` without quotes

Comment: First question what makes some columns not to be editable, filterable or non visible what is the goal of it *"controlling"* it on the client side in JavaScript?

Comment: @RaymondNijland I'm using material-table (https://material-table.com/#/) . It allows you to enable/disable features like filtering and so on within the table. Sometimes the table columns I am dynamically getting will require these settings to be true or false. Knowing where to store this information is my issue. I could probably do this server-side to, but the question still remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if anyone stumbles upon this, I simply used a JSON file to store all the information I need about specific table columns, e.g. :

```
{
    "table1": {
        "id": {
            "type": "numeric",
            "hidden": false,
            "filtering": true,
            "editable": "never"
        },
        "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "hidden": false,
            "filtering": true,
            "editable": null
        },
    },
    "table2": {
        "phone": {
            "type": "string",
            "hidden": false,
            "filtering": true,
            "editable": null
        },
        "age": {
            "type": "numeric",
            "hidden": false,
            "filtering": true,
            "editable": null
        }
    }
}
```

I get this file in my server-side php and send everything to my frontend. Now I can access values via props in my React project.

```
    //use map function to create columns from column_fields in props
    let i = 0;
    let columns = props.column_fields.map(column => {
        i++;
        if (column.field != 'updated_at') {
            return ({
                title: column.field, field: column.field, type: props.column_fields[i - 1].type, editable: props.column_fields[i - 1].editable,
                filtering: props.column_fields[i - 1].filtering, hidden: props.column_fields[i - 1].hidden
            })
        }
    })
```

Hopefully this method works out long term.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
const props = { column_fields: ["id", "name", "age"] };

const column_settings = {
  id: {
    type: "string",
    editable: true,
    filtering: true,
    editable: true,
    hidden: false
  },
  name: {
    type: "string",
    editable: true,
    filtering: true,
    editable: true,
    hidden: false
  },
  age: {
    type: "number",
    editable: true,
    filtering: true,
    editable: true,
    hidden: false
  }
};

//use map function to create columns from column_fields in props
const columns2 = props.column_fields.map(column_name => {
  return (
    //TODO: correctly configure all attributes
    {
      title: column_name,
      field: column_name,
      ...column_settings[column_name]
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: Yes but the true and false values are hard-coded. My code is dynamic so that no matter what table is being retrieved from the database or what columns there are, the settings are custom to the specific table. For example, I may call data from another table and that table might require age to be hidden.

Comment: it's probably just a template the data for it you may retrieve from rest endpoint I believe. it's hard to follow what you need as you provided not all info so I can understand your problem